# Got the ERROR 1046* CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activity` (

Tags: mysql

Table structure for table `activity`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activity` (
  `fnum` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fid` int(25) default NULL,
  `fdate` datetime default NULL,
  `ftask` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`fnum`),
  KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1204 ;
```

MySQL said:

## 1046 - No database selected

Comment: Perhaps you should select a database...

Comment: Are you trying to import an existing SQL file from within phpMyAdmin or entering this SQL directly (in to the SQL tab)?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says "1046 - No database selected". You should start your script with selecting a database. E.g.:

```
use my_database;
```